# External evaluation vs. internal evaluation: how to highlight differences

Tags: usability, user-attention

A friend of mine is working as a bus driver in public transportation. They have an application for their passengers and they are now starting a project for evaluating drivers. Passengers can evaluate manners of the bus driver (friendliness, punctuality, style of driving etc.). Also the driver can evaluate himself. Everything is done in an online/mobile application. My friend is part of the project team to provide feedback from the front and we discussed the obvious options.

In our discussion these questions arised on the overall UX:

1. Would it be better to provide pre-defined evaluation topics (friendliness, punctuality, style of driving etc.) and let passengers and the bus driver rate them or provide two free-text fields (with suggestions) for mentioning good manners and the ones which need to be improved?
2. Is there a better UX to capture topics and evaluations beside the two mentioned in #1?
3. What would be the best way to communicate differences to the bus drivers? I tend to open a task in the application as soon as a particular threshhold is exceeded. Then the application sends a notification via email or push notifications to the bus drivers to log into the application. The application itself highlights the differences to them. This probably works only for pre-defined evaluation topics and not free-text fields.

Answer (score 1):

I think if it is a voluntary survey, people would have a tendency to go through it mainly if they are dissatisfied and want to give negative feedback.

I would suggest splitting the process in two stages:

- For the **first stage**, **keep it (extremely) simple** - in the end, everything sums up to the Customer satisfaction. You could use a **simple satisfaction measuring** approach, just like *Happy or Not* that would be located inside the bus (these guys got it right regarding the in-store,  in-airport, in-institution etc. satisfaction): https://www.happy-or-not.com/en/measure/#smiley-terminal

[image]

The results would need to be automatically **connected with particular driver**,

- As far as the **second stage** is concerned, some Customers could be **invited to go through an extended survey**. It is important that they would be randomly selected, as this way you would avoid, at least partially, the effect of giving mostly negative feedback. You could do it by printing out a receipt with e.g. a unique ID to be entered on a survey site. The customer should be informed that they **help to improve the service, which is for them**.

Additionally, you could **give Customers something in return** for going through the survey. These may be various things: you may require from them to go through it to use the service next time, they may get discounts, or you can make them feel they are on a mission of improving the service etc.

In your case, they might get e.g. a day of free fare, based on the very receipt they would receive and an additional code they would receive upon completion of the survey.

**For the survey itself** – I believe that you should **split the driver evaluation from the service evaluation**.

I think the initial check of the passenger satisfaction would be a measure good enough for evaluating a driver, making them (drivers) feel good, as they should not feel they are checked in every dimension of their work, but valued if passengers are satisfied in general.

The further, detailed survey, should give answers to questions regarding the way the service is constructed.

I believe that this way you would **make everyone feel that it matters to you** that they (both passengers and drivers) are happy, while not making the drivers feel that they are put under some control. And making people feel that they are valued and on a mission always gives better results than making them feel they are controlled.